# merge a group of template specializations

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have 3 function template specializations, having exactly the same code. I have tried for a while, but I could not succeed to merge them into a single template expression. Here is a sample:

```
template <typename Event>
void aFunction(const Event &anEvent){
    // do nothing for other types
}
template <>
void aFunction(const InsertEvent &anEvent){
    std::cout<<"aFunction"<<std::endl;
}
template <>
void aFunction(const RemoveEvent &anEvent){
    std::cout<<"aFunction"<<std::endl;
}
template <>
void aFunction(const ChangeEvent &anEvent){
    std::cout<<"aFunction"<<std::endl;
}
```

edit:
I have tried to merge them using std::enable_if_t and I have been able to proceed as follows:

```
template <typename Event>
typename std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same<Event, InsertEvent>::value &&
    !std::is_same<Event, RemoveEvent>::value &&
    !std::is_same<Event, ChangeEvent>::value>
aFunction(const Event &anEvent){
    // do nothing for other types
}
template <typename Event>
typename std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<Event, InsertEvent>::value ||
    std::is_same<Event, RemoveEvent>::value ||
    std::is_same<Event, ChangeEvent>::value>
aFunction(const Event &anEvent){
    std::cout<<"aFunction"<<std::endl;
}
```

Instead, is it possible to get rid of the !std::is_same<..> lines for the more general template case?

Comment: Do you want it to "do nothing" on other types, but error out in the event of other types?

Comment: do nothing on other types (SFINAE)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible way:

```
template <typename Event>
void aFunction(const Event &anEvent, std::false_type){
    // do nothing for other types
}

template <typename Event>
void aFunction(const Event &anEvent, std::true_type){
    std::cout<<"aFunction"<<std::endl;
}

template <typename Event>
void aFunction(const Event &anEvent){
    aFunction(anEvent, std::integral_constant<bool, 
        std::is_same_v<Event, InsertEvent> ||
        std::is_same_v<Event, RemoveEvent> ||
        std::is_same_v<Event, ChangeEvent>>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qfsdTl)

Comment: Thank you, I think there could be a more elegant and compile time approach rather than calling another function inside at runtime.

Comment: The call is very likely to get inlined. In my demo, it did.

Comment: is it possible to change the std::true_type and false_type into a template argument instead of a function? Then, we could guarantee compile time resolution.

Comment: If you make it a template argument, then you'd need partial specialization. But there ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template - you'd need to delegate to a helper class template. At which point you'd be right back to a forwarding call.

Comment: Starting with C++17, you could use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If). But you stipulated C++14, so that's unavailable.

Comment: However, I was able to merge them with enable_if_t, please see the updated version. Now, I am considering of reducing the boilerplate code.

Comment: You could encapsulate the chain of `is_same` instantiations into your own trait, like `IsSpecialEventType`. At least you wouldn't have to list them twice.